# How can the scope be changed in a WinForms app to carry variables from a method to an object sender?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, variables, scope

I am trying to carry the variables from the array over to the button click action. I can't find the way to set the scope to allow for this to work.

I have tried changing the modifiers to public, private, static, void, string, string[] etc.

I have also made all of the objects in the WinForms app set to Public

```
public partial class AutoPay : Form
{

    public AutoPay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void HeaderInformation(string dateAndTime, string fileNumber)
    {
        dateAndTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        fileNumber = txtFileNumber.Text;

   string[] headerArray = new string[2];
        headerArray[0] = dateAndTime;
        headerArray[1] = fileNumber;
    }

    public void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HeaderInformation(headerArray[0], headerArray[1]);
    }

}
```

the headerArray[0] under the BtnSave_Click action has the red line under it showing that it is outside of the scope.

Comment: Why do you pass `dateAndTime` and `fileNumber` to `HeaderInformation` if you don't use it but overwrite it? And what effect on the object's or the environment's state does it have if you just create an array to the method? You might as well just remove `HeaderInformation` and leave `BtnSave_Click` empty or also remove it. The outcome seems to be the same...

Comment: You dont explicitly "set the scope".  *Where* you declare a variable determines the scope.  Something declared at the form or class level will be available everywhere in the form/class.  Things declared in methods (including event handlers) arr available only there. `headerArray` only exists in `HeaderInformation` because that is where it is declared.

Answer (score 2):

Try declaring the headerArray as a Property of the class

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned... you need to declare the headerArray outside the method... Also... it looks like you are trying to add information to the array before the array has information... try it this way(there are many other ways to do this too ;) ):

```
public partial class AutoPay : Form
{

  private string[] headerArray;   // <-- declare it here...

  public AutoPay()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    headerArray = new string[2];  // <-- sometimes the normal way to initialize...
  }

  public void HeaderInformation(string dateAndTime, string fileNumber)
  {
    // reinitialize headerArray for safety....
    headerArray = new string[2];
    headerArray[0] = dateAndTime;
    headerArray[1] = fileNumber;
  }

  public void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    HeaderInformation(DateTime.Now.ToString(), txtFileNumber.Text);
  }

}
```

or

```
public void HeaderInformation()
{
    // reinitialize headerArray for safety....
    headerArray = new string[2];
    headerArray[0] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    headerArray[1] = txtFileNumber.Text;
}

public void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HeaderInformation();
}
```